# Why doesn't my Jquery code work more than once on my dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a dropdown in html id tagged as "area" with values.
Another dropdown tagged as car with optgroups of the areas and a full list of cars.

What I am trying to accomplish is to filter the too long dropdown of cars into a smaller manageable list, and thus my reason for the first dropdown of area.

The Jquery code below hides the full list of cars and creates a temporary dropdown with just the selected optgroup data:

```
$('select#car').after('<select id="parkingLot"><option value="0">ALL</option></select>');
$('select#car').hide();
$('select#area').change(function() {
  var area = $(this).val();
  $("#parkingLot").html($('select#car optgroup[label="' + area  + '"]'));
});
```

This code works, but only once per optgroup. Example: if you select area 1 and check the second dropdown it displays correctly, then check area 2 and it display correctly, however area 1 does not work after checking it again.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: not sure what you trying to do but may be its due to even binding

Comment: Add some `html` too and create a **fiddle** if possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because you are moving the optgroup from the original select

```js
$('#car').after('<select id="parkingLot"><option value="0">ALL</option></select>');
$('#car').hide();
$('#area').change(function() {
  var area = $(this).val();
  $("#parkingLot").html($('#car optgroup[label="' + area + '"]').clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="car">
  <optgroup label="a1">
    <option>a1.1</option>
    <option>a1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="a2">
    <option>a2.1</option>
    <option>a2.2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="a3">
    <option>a3.1</option>
    <option>a3.2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="a4">
    <option>a4.1</option>
    <option>a4.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<select id="area">
  <option></option>
  <option>a1</option>
  <option>a2</option>
  <option>a3</option>
  <option>a4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it would be more helpful if you add  why your code will work ?

Comment: This is the correct answer, and I will mark it when stackoverflow allows me to. Well spotted! I need now to understand why jquery would do this? It doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: @Nightwolf when you say `$("#parkingLot").html($('select#car optgroup[label="' + area  + '"]'));`... it find the target `optgroup` and move it from `#car` to `#parkingLot` element... now that `optgroup` does not exists in the `#car` element.... so second time it is not able to find the element

Comment: @Nightwolf if you see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vo0nxgk0/2/ - after selecting an area... that particular item is removed form `#car`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I understood exactly that, however I was thinking in code: "variable A_content = variable B_content" in code that would leave variable B_content intact. I believe I now have a better grasp why JQuery does that.